# Group report items

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am trying to create report in SSRS 2008, which more or less looks like any consumer statements. Meaning, I need to display"Bill To address" and "bill number" on the report for each bill number. Then I need to provide details for each bill number.

I need to repeat this for each bill number.

Here is the example:

```
BillTo
Clark
1111, Noth St
New york
USA

Bill Number:111111

Line Items                Qty       amount
1                           1         1000
2                           2         2000
```

Repeat above for customer 2

```
BillTo
John
1111, Noth St
New york
USA

Bill Number:111111

Line Items                Qty       amount
1                           2          500
2                           2         2000
```

I am using text boxes for address and placing on report body and I am using table for the detail.

I don't know how to group these report items to repeat for each Bill Number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a group and group by your bill number. This article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170712.aspx) will walk you through the process and I'm happy to answer any questions you have.